# JQuery - callback on function? ($.Deferred)

Tags: ajax, jquery

I currently have a function that looks like this:

```
$(function(){
 $('.chained_to_vehicle_make_selector').remoteChainedTo('.chained_parent_vehicle_make_selector', '/models.json');
 $('.chained_to_vehicle_model_selector').remoteChainedTo('.chained_parent_vehicle_model_selector', '/trims.json');
 $('.chained_to_vehicle_trim_selector').remoteChainedTo('.chained_parent_vehicle_trim_selector', '/model_years.json');
});
```

As you can probably tell, each remoteChainedTo function is making an AJAX call, which is working fine, but takes a bit of time.

I then have a second code block:

```
$(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    $(".chained_parent_vehicle_make_selector").chosen().change( function() {$(".chained_to_vehicle_make_selector").trigger("liszt:updated"); });
    $(".chained_parent_vehicle_model_selector").chosen().change( function() {$(".chained_to_vehicle_model_selector").trigger("liszt:updated"); });
    $(".chained_parent_vehicle_trim_selector").chosen().change( function() {$(".chained_to_vehicle_trim_selector").trigger("liszt:updated"); });
    $(".chained_child").chosen();
});
```

This section of the code works fine as long as it fires *after* the first section is complete. Because of the AJAX calls, however, it is currently firing before the previous section.

How can I implement a structure so that the second code block always fires after the first block is completely done? The remoteChainedTo function does not have a defined callback (that I can see), and in any case it would be impossible to know which of the three calls will finish last, hence wanting to put the callback somehow on the block, so that the second section of code fires only after the last AJAX call completes.

EDIT: After a bit more refactoring, my code now looks as follows:

```
function makeChains(){
 $('.chained_to_vehicle_make_selector').remoteChainedTo('.chained_parent_vehicle_make_selector', '/models.json');
 $('.chained_to_vehicle_model_selector').remoteChainedTo('.chained_parent_vehicle_model_selector', '/trims.json');
 $('.chained_to_vehicle_trim_selector').remoteChainedTo('.chained_parent_vehicle_trim_selector', '/model_years.json');
}

var chainCall = $(function() {
    makeChains();
});

chainCall.done(function() { 
        $(".chzn-select").chosen();
        $(".chained_parent_vehicle_make_selector").chosen().change( function() {$(".chained_to_vehicle_make_selector").trigger("liszt:updated"); });
        $(".chained_parent_vehicle_model_selector").chosen().change( function() {$(".chained_to_vehicle_model_selector").trigger("liszt:updated"); });
        $(".chained_parent_vehicle_trim_selector").chosen().change( function() {$(".chained_to_vehicle_trim_selector").trigger("liszt:updated"); });
        $(".chained_child").chosen();
    });
```

But i'm still getting the error `Object [object Object] has no method 'done'`. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Read up on deferreds - http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/, http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: In addition to @MikeRobinson - this is a nice article http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/ since the documentation may be confusing if you see the deferreds for the first time